# Building graphs between two point layers

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, network, qgis-grass-plugin

I am trying to run a script to find the shortest routes between two sets of point layers  (Blue star and Green dots) in QGIS using road network. I am able to use GRASS gis "v.net.distance" for 1 star at a time (see picture below). I am trying for multiple stars at a time but can't iterate more than one layer at using the plugin GUI. I was trying to use network analysis library in PYQGIS using some online scripts but no success so far.

How can I do this?

[image: ShortestPaths]